# "Common to" OR "Common in"

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition is used with common when I mean to say that these features are common in/to all the applications?
Is there another way to write this type of a sentence?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OP should probably use **to** in his exact context. The (slight) difference can be illustrated by...

> 1: DNA is common **to** all life on earth
>    ***every instance*** of "life" on earth contains DNA ("common **to**" = **always present in**).
>
> 2: DNA is common **in** all life on earth
>    *DNA is **commonly found, unexceptional**, in all life on earth ("common" = **widespread**)*.